# What could be different between these two PHP string assignments?

Tags: php, wordpress

This a variation on my [Why doesn't update_post_meta work for certain strings?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36689/why-doesnt-update-post-meta-work-for-certain-strings) question on [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). I have brought it here because I suspect this is more likely a pure PHP issue than just a WordPress one.

My question is based around the following code:

```
$upload = wp_handle_upload ( $_FILES [WPSM_MAIL_META_ATTACHMENT], array ('test_form' => false ) );
$path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ReSharper-6.1-License.txt';
var_dump($path);
$path = $upload['file'];
var_dump($path);
die();
update_post_meta ( 34, WPSM_MAIL_META_ATTACHMENT, $path );
```

The `update_post_meta` call updates the `WPSM_MAIL_META_ATTACHMENT` column in the WordPress database for post no. 34. The string literal assignment in line 2 gives `$path` exactly the same value as the array member assignment does in line 4, yet with the code as it is, the `WPSM_MAIL_META_ATTACHMENT` column is updated to an empty string. If I comment out line 4, therefore using only the literal assignment, the `WPSM_MAIL_META_ATTACHMENT` column is updated to the correct file path value.

I can only imagine that the two different strings assigned to `$path` differ in some way that is invisible to me with my very noob debugging tools `var_dump` and `die`. How can I go about diagnosing what is different between the two cases I describe above? Or, as a compromise, is there anything I can do to modify the `$path = $upload['file']` assignment so that I get the same outcome as with the literal assignment?

The output in my browser window after this code executes is exactly as follows, reproduced as is, on a single line, for fidelity's sake:

```
string(78) "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ReSharper-6.1-License.txt" string(78) "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ReSharper-6.1-License.txt"
```

Comment: did you intend to mix slashes in your $path variable?

Comment: Please post the two `var_dump` results.

Comment: Can you ensure is not using double quote in here ? `$upload['file']; = "...";`

Comment: @scunliffe I copied the string as output by var_dump. WordPress is mixing the slashes somewhere in the `$upload = wp_handle_upload ( $_FILES [WPSM_MAIL_META_ATTACHMENT], array ('test_form' => false ) )` call just above the code I have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to trace and require some source code digging :-

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/post.php

  - http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/meta.php

    - http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/formatting.php
  - http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/plugin.php

Turn out should be related to function `stripslahses_deep`, and `apply_filter`

```
php > $path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ReSharper-6.1-License.txt';
php > var_dump ( stripslashes_deep($path));
string(75) "C:xampphtdocswordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ReSharper-6.1-License.txt"
```

If you do this :-

```
php > var_dump ( stripslashes_deep( addslashes($path) ) );
string(78) "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ReSharper-6.1-License.txt"
```

I don't have the definite conclusion,
likely is caused by slashes

To start a quick debug,
try to test value with

```
/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ReSharper-6.1-License.txt
C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ReSharper-6.1-License.txt
```